# Why would surgery theory require $5$ dimensions?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, surgery-theory

In the Wikipedia page for [geometric topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_topology) it says "The Whitney trick requires $2+1$ dimensions, hence surgery theory requires $5$ dimensions".  I am having trouble with understanding why surgical theory would have to require five dimensions and why it would not work with less dimensions.

Comment: If you are truly interested in this, I'd suggest reading Milnor's Notes on the h-cobordism theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a complicated subject, but the main idea is that you need to turn collections of spheres $S^n$ in $2n$-dimensions into disjoint embeddings in order to get surgery to work. The main tool for turning a sphere into an embedded sphere is the Whitney trick. If a sphere intersects another sphere in two algebraically cancelling points, form a circle by connecting the two intersection points by arcs on each of the two spheres. If this is null-homotopic, you can fill it in with a disk. In dimensions higher than $4$, this disk is generically embedded, so can be used to guide a Whitney move that removes the two canceling intersections. However, in dimension $4$, the Whitney disk generically intersects both itself and the spheres.

This [introduction to an old paper of mine](http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/108/20/8131.full.pdf) should also help give context. Even though the Whitney move fails in this dimension, we looked at iterated towers of Whitney moves, which did lead to interesting information.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps out immensely